# appending date with filename using batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to set a housekeeping for different type of file. PFB scenario.

I have below set of files in a network path(**\NAS.domain.local\data\Arasan**)

- test.sql
- test1.txt
- test2.log

I am trying to rename the files as shown below and move the files to .\Archive\ directory

- Test_15-12-2016_151428.sql
- Test1_15-12-2016_151428.txt
- Test_15-12-2016_151428.log

**([Filename]_DD-MM-YYYY_HHMISS.[ext])**

I have built the below batch script.

```
@echo ON
SET Log_Path=\\NAS.domain.local\data\Arasan
SET Script_Path=C:\Scripts

REM ###########################################REM
REM ## Do make any changes to the text below ##REM
REM ###########################################REM

cd %Script_Path%
pushd %Log_Path%
dir /b /a-d > %Script_Path%\list.txt
set HH=%TIME:~0,8%
for /F %%A in (%Script_Path%\list.txt) do (
    setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
    set ffname=%%A
    set "fname=%%~nA"
    set "fext=%%~xA"
    ren !ffname! !fname!_%DATE%_%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%!fext!
endlocal
)
del %Script_Path%\list.txt
move *.* Archive\
popd
exit
```

Now my issue is it is working perfectly in my machine but when I transfer this to server and execute. It is 
throwing "**The syntax of the command is incorrect.**" Error.
And it is moving the files without renaming. As for as i know, file name and extension is not being assigned to the variable properly in below part

```
set ffname=%%A
 set "fname=%%~nA"
 set "fext=%%~xA"
```

Server OS: Windows server 2008 R2 Standard(SP1)

Can anyone please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the part of the code you should be using to get a consistent date and time output:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime') Do For %%B In (%%~nA
) Do Set "DTS=%%B"
Set "DTS=_%DTS:~6,2%-%DTS:~4,2%-%DTS:~,4%_%DTS:~-6%"
Echo( [%DTS%]
Pause
```

Just incorporate this into the rest of your code…

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Let me check and get back to you. :)

Comment: Its perfect, Thanks a lot brother :).